# Minimization problem for convolution

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $g(x)$ be a non-negative function supported on $[0,1]$. Let $g \ast g$ denote the convolution of $g$ with itself. Question: What is the smallest possible $L^1(0,1)$ norm of $g$, if I require that $(g \ast g) (t) \geq 1$ for all $t \in [0,1]$.

Clearly one needs $\|g\|_1 \geq 1$. However, $\|g\|_1=1$ cannot be achieved. But what is the best value that can actually be achieved?

(Maybe the optimizing function is explicitly known? Something like $g(x) = 1/\sqrt{\pi x}$ works and gives $\|g\|_1 \approx 1.13$, but probably something smaller is possible.)

Comment: Interestingly, exactly the same norm $\|g\|_1 = 2/\sqrt{\pi} \approx 1.13$ is attained both by $g(x) = (\pi x)^{-1/2}$ and by $g(x) = \max\{(\pi x)^{-1/2},(\pi (1/2-x))^{-1/2}\} \mathbb{1}_{(0,1/2)}(x)$.

Comment: Silly question. Is the reason that  the L_1 norm lower bound of 1 cannot be achieved the normalization of the Fourier transform on [0,1]?

Comment: The Fourier transform of an indicator function is not non-negative real. In contrast, a convolution of a function with itself leads to a non-negative real Fourier transform (since we are squaring). So 1 cannot be reached exactly. However, I don't have an estimate how close to 1 one can actually get.

Comment: Sorry for being silly, but which consequences you make from squaring a complex-valued function?

Comment: I would rather say that the Laplace transform of the uniform distribution is not a square of an entire function, due to the behaviour at zeroes.

Answer (score 5):

Rick Barnard and I looked at the same problem for the auto-convolution instead of the convolution: [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.08731). Our constants are a bit worse because you basically need two square-root singularities, one on each side. These types of inequalities tend to be relevant in combinatorics and they tend to be pretty hard (we discuss some in our paper). One I like a lot can be found in [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60087/can-h%C3%B6lders-inequality-be-strengthened-for-smooth-functions). (I would have commented but you need 50 reputation for that, sorry.)

Answer (score 4):

(Too long for a comment.)

Numerical experiments suggests that one cannot do better than $1 / \sqrt{\pi x}$ (or one of the equivalent variants, the set of minimizers appears to be quite large). Here is a plot of three minimizers obtained numerically for the discrete analogue of the problem on $\{0, 1, 2, \ldots, n - 1\}$ with $n = 75$. These minimizers were found by Mathematica with three different numerical optimization methods (blue: `"DifferentialEvolution"`, yellow: `"NelderMead"`, green: `"SimmulatedAnnealing"`). The corresponding norms are 1.12145, 1.12842, 1.1265, respectively.

[image]

Mathematica code:

```
n = 75;
expr = Sum[x[i], {i, 0, n - 1}]/Sqrt[n];
constr = Join[
   Table[Sum[x[j] x[i - j], {j, 0, i}] >= 1, {i, 0, n - 1}], 
   Table[x[i] >= 0, {i, 0, n - 1}]];
vars = Table[x[i], {i, 0, n - 1}];
{min1, subst1} = 
  NMinimize[{expr, constr}, vars, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"];
{min2, subst2} = 
  NMinimize[{expr, constr}, vars, Method -> "NelderMead"];
{min3, subst3} = 
  NMinimize[{expr, constr}, vars, Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing"];
{min1, min2, min3}
ListPlot[{vars /. subst1, vars /. subst2, vars /. subst3}, 
 Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Have you found any other minimizers in an analytical form?

Comment: I have not tried that, but apparently one can find intermediate solutions between the two that I mentioned in my comment. If I find time later today, I will see if I can figure out the details.

Comment: I am not quite sure if that has any real significance. The numerical values I get using the same code for n=85 are {1.12831, 1.12672, 1.1287}, and for n=95 they are {1.12594, 1.13249, 1.1269}. In comparison, $2 / \sqrt{\pi} \approx 1.1284$.

Comment: Note that $x_k = \tfrac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots (2k-1)}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdots 2k}$ solves $\sum_{j=0}^i x_j x_{i-j}=1$ exactly and has the same asymptotic $2\sqrt{n}/\sqrt{\pi}$. However, your data suggests that it is possible to improve on this a little for finite $n$.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer: This explicit solution corresponds to the green line in the plot, I believe. I am not sure if one can really improve upon this, differences between minimizers found by different algorithms seem to be within the range of admissible error.

Comment: @KurisutoAsutora For $n=95$, I computed $L:=\sum_{k=0}^{94} \tfrac{1 \cdot 3 \cdots (2k-1)}{2 \cdot 4 \cdots (2k)}$ in exact arithmetic (it is a rational number) and then computed  $\tfrac{L}{\sqrt{95}}$ with Mathematica using 20 digits of internal precision. I got 1.12689544 and I believe all those digits are right. Are all the digits of your 1.12594 provably achievable? (I.e. has your algorithm definitely found a point which achiees this?) If so, this is what I mean when I see you can improve a little.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer: Interesting. I just did the same calculation for $n = 50$ ($n = 95$ takes too long on my laptop), and I am surprised to find that indeed one can improve slightly upon the explicit solution that you mentioned! Details: Explicit solution has norm 1.12556. Mathematica implementation of the Nelder–Mead method leads to a "solution" that has norm 1.11968. (1/2)

Comment: @DavidESpeyer: However, three out of fifty conditions $x*x(i)\geqslant 1$ are not satisfied by this solution: they are off by roughly $10^{-9}$ (this is how the numerical method is supposed to work). Still, $\tilde{x}(i) = x(i)+10^{-8}$ is a true solution with norm 1.11968 (this is the norm of $x$ plus $10^{-8} \sqrt{50}$), less than the norm of the explicit solution. (2/2)

Comment: @DavidESpeyer: No, I do not claim that I have any "provable" numerical result, this is just what Mathematica returned after I used Mateusz' code, with the only change of replacing n=75 by n=95. I did not make any effort to control the size of errors.

Comment: PS: As a general remark, I am more interested in the continuous problem, not in the discrete one. So in the discretization probably one would need to obtain some asymptotics as $n \to \infty$, to say something about the continuous problem.